# Playframework changing value in ebean database

Tags: java, html, playframework, routes

It's not possible for me to change the value punten of a ploeg. I made a button which triggers a function that will change the points but nothing happens. This is my button:

```
@form(routes.Application.geefPunten(ploeg.id)) {
    <input type="submit" value="Gewonnen">
}
```

This is the function it calls within my Aaplication.java:

```
public static Result geefPunten(Long id) {
    Ploeg.geefPunt(id);
    return redirect(routes.Application.ploegen());
}
```

And then this is the function in my Ploeg.java which should change the value of punten:

```
public static void geefPunt(Long id) {
    Ploeg ploegje = find.byId(id);
    ploegje.punten = ploegje.punten + 3;

}
```

And this is my routes file where I think it is going wrong:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Ploegen
GET     /ploegen                    controllers.Application.ploegen()
# POST    /ploeg/:id                  controllers.Ploeg.zoekPloeg(id: Long)
POST    /ploegen/:id/punten         controllers.Application.geefPunten(id: Long)
POST    /ploegen/:id/delete         controllers.Application.deletePloeg(id: Long)
POST    /ploegen/maak               controllers.Application.maakPloeg()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I personally think it is going wrong with the routes but I can't find the problem. Have been searching for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it after you changed it:

```
ploegje.save();
```

Comment: Thanks! sometimes those little mistakes are the hardest to find